# jQuery throwing up "Unexpected token for" as an error

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, token

I have absolutely no idea what the problem is, but the following throws up "Unexpected token for" on the for loop below.

Removing the for loop causes the closing }; to be called an unexpected token.

```
$.fn.appExt = function() {

        $(data).find('a').each(function() {

                fileExt = this.href.replace(window.location, '').replace('localhost/Program/Code', '').split('.')[1];

                if ($.inArray(fileExt, ext) == -1 && typeof fileExt !== 'undefined') {
                    ext.push(fileExt);
                }

            }

            // here lies the problem apparently
            for (i = 0; i < ext.length; i++) {
                $('#ext').append('<h5>' + ext[i] + '</h5>');
            }

        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `);` to close the call to `.each()`, but you could also add some `var` keywords so you aren't creating global variables:

```
$.fn.appExt = function () {
    $(data).find('a').each(function () {
        var fileExt = this.href.replace(window.location,
            '').replace('localhost/Program/Code', '').split('.')[1]; // [1] Added "var"

        if ($.inArray(fileExt, ext) == -1 && typeof fileExt !== 'undefined') {
            ext.push(fileExt);
        }
    }); // [2] Added ");"

    for (var i = 0; i < ext.length; i++) { // [3] Added "var"
        $('#ext').append('<h5>' + ext[i] + '</h5>');
    }
};
```

You should neatly indent your code so the intent is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed your each function parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.each` function looks like this:

```
$(data).find('a').each(function() { };
```

which means you missed the closing parenthesis for `.each(`

Whenever you start a tag first thing to do should be adding its closing tag before you put something within the tags:

```
 $(data).find('a').each(function() { 
       //ready to add the code
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not close your .each function parentheses.